# Updating textbox value on submit

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I thought I resolved my previous question but here I am again. I've got a page with a simple react component containing an input, button, and textbox.
[image: goal component]

When the page loads it pulls the value from a MongoDB collection. It passes that to the component and the component should take that prop and display it in the textbox. I am able to show the value on initial loading.

Here is the code from the parent that passes the value to the goal component:

`Goal goal={dashboardinfo}`

Where dashboard info is in this case

> $20,000

The goal component receives the prop

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";

import Form from "react-bootstrap/Form";
import { Row, Col, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "./../css/Goal.css";

const Goal = (props) => {
  let [goal, setgoal] = useState("");

  const goalUpdate = (event) => {
    setgoal(event.target.value);
    console.log("after-set goal", goal);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setgoal(props.goal);
  }, [props.goal]);


  return (
    <Form onSubmit={goalUpdate}>
      <Row className="align-items-center flex">
        <Col sm={3} className="goal sm={3}">
          <Form.Control
            className="goal"
            id="inlineFormInputGoal"
            placeholder="Goal"
            required
            onChange={goalUpdate}
          />
          <Button type="submit" className="submit btn-3">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <h1 className="text-box">Goal: {goal}</h1>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default Goal;
```

The useEffect updates the textbox with the props as expected. When I type in the input box, the onChange updates the textbox. But when I hit the submit, the input box is cleared out and the textbox goes back to the original props value. I cannot get the new value to stick. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried to set the value of the input?

value={goal}

That useEffect will give you more problems than benefits, since, it will run anytime props.goals change, i don't know if you are receiving goals in props, but you have an state value called goals also, which is confusing. I recommend to rename or remove that useEffect

Answer (score 0):

The page is reloading when the submit button is hit, so it is causing the original value from mongoDb to be displayed. In your goalUpdate function if you add an event.preventDefault() that should stop the submit button refreshing the page when it's clicked.

Comment: When I add that to goalUpdate, the textbox shows the input as I type in the input box and when I submit it updates the variable `code`,                                                                 **`after-set goal 9999`**. But the actual textbox now just shows _Goal:_.

Answer (score 0):

`event.preventDefault()` should go inside the function called during submit to prevent form from being submitted.

```
 const goalUpdate = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault() //add this...
    setgoal(event.target.value);
    console.log("after-set goal", goal);
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const Goal = (props) => {
  let [goal, setgoal] = useState("");
    let [updatedGoal, setUpdatedGoal] = useState("")

  const onGoalValueChange = (event) => {
    setgoal(event.target.value);
    console.log("after-set goal", goal);
  };

//to handle updating value to new
  const updateGoal = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault()
    setUpdatedGoal(goal)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setgoal(props.goal);
  }, [props.goal]);


  return (
    <Form onSubmit={updateGoal}>  value
      <Row className="align-items-center flex">
        <Col sm={3} className="goal sm={3}">
          <Form.Control
            className="goal"
            id="inlineFormInputGoal"
            placeholder="Goal"
            required
            onChange={onGoalValueChange} // to handle value change in textbox
          />
          <Button type="submit" className="submit btn-3">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </Col>
        <Col>
          <h1 className="text-box">Goal: {updatedGoal !== undefined || updateGoal !== "" ? updateGoal || newGoal}</h1> // usually this will be props but doing this just for visual purpose
        </Col>
      </Row>
    </Form>
  );
};
export default Goal;
```

Updating my answer to make things work - similar to what I said in my comment (handling changed value and onSubmit value)

Comment: When I put the event.preventDefault() in the goalUpdate function and submit, it doesn't show the updated goal on the screen, it now just shows _Goal:_

Comment: Okay, so here's what happening.
`onChange` gets and stores value from your input into the `goal` state. As long as you don't submit, the value from your `goal` state is displayed in your `<h1>`.

Now, in order for you to get the new updated value in your <h1> after submit, you will need to get this value as a prop. Think of this as sending the new value to db and then getting it back (like you're getting it on the first render).

Flow should be: get value from input -> save it to db -> get the value again from db -> value gets passed as prop -> new value shws up in <h1> tag.

Comment: If you want to display the newly added value after submit, you will need to send it to db, change the existing value in db, and then get that value, which will show up in UI as new value (after submit)